# Generate STS token with assume_role_with_web_identity

Tags: python, kubernetes, boto3, amazon-eks, aws-sts

I am looking to generate AWS token in my kubernetes pod  using AWS_ROLE_ARN & AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE specified in this documentation [EKS Service Accounts](https://eksctl.io/usage/iamserviceaccounts/). Would be able to generate the token using the code below or should I extract the token from AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE before it can be passed as WebIdentityToken?

```
client = boto3.client('sts')
response = client.assume_role_with_web_identity(
    RoleArn=os.environ['AWS_ROLE_ARN'],
    RoleSessionName='mySession',
    WebIdentityToken=os.environ['AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE']
)
```

Comment: Are you using EKS or DIY Kubernetes (kops, etc.)?

Comment: I am using EKS.

Comment: OK, then why would you want to do this? :)

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I saw a "no credentials provided" error. So I thought I need to generate the credentials!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure but I recommend that you peruse https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/ ;)